# BouncyCastle TLS клиент, проблема с реализацией получения Server PublicKey

Tags: c#, .net

1. Как реализовать получение `Server Certificate PublicKey` из унаследованного `MyTlsClient`?
2. Как задать версию клиентского `TLS` протокола?

Пример кода:

```
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Tls;

public class MyTlsClient : DefaultTlsClient
{
    public override TlsAuthentication GetAuthentication()
    {
        return new MyTlsAuthentication();
    }
}

public class MyTlsAuthentication : TlsAuthentication
{
    public TlsCredentials GetClientCredentials(CertificateRequest certificateRequest)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void NotifyServerCertificate(Certificate serverCertificate)
    {
        // validate server certificate
    }
}


// Использование
var sr = new Org.BouncyCastle.Security.SecureRandom();
var tlsStream = new TlsClientProtocol(networkStream, sr);
var tlsClient = new MyTlsClient();
tlsStream.Connect(tlsClient);
```